# Can't use collectcell within environment on last column if missing trailing \\ on last line

Tags: tables, collcell

Well it's embarrassing question time again.  What am I doing wrong here with [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell)? I have used this pacakge often, but am stumped on this trivial example.

I have defined a `newcolumntype`, `C` which applies a color to the text.  This works fine, but *only* on the first column. It fails if I attempt to use on the second column with:

> ! Argument of `\collect@cell@arg` has an extra }.  
>                   `\par`  l.20  `a &
>             b \\`

The MWE as below yields the following which illustrates that the `collcell` package is doing its job:

[image]

### Notes:

- This example could certainly be done with just the `array` pacakge, but I need to use `collcell` as there is more processing that needs to be done.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\NewData}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\NewData}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1]{% ignore user specified column spec for now...
    \begin{tabular}{Cr}% <--- This works just fine
    %\begin{tabular}{rC}% <--- but this does not!!
    %\begin{tabular}{CC}% <--- neither does this does (I want this)!!
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyTabular}{ll}
    a & b \\
    c & d
\end{MyTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's documented, but it works if the second row ends with ``\\``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation about `collcell` says it works also in the last cell, that  should not be empty if the `norobustcr` option is called.

However it appears that when hidden in an environment, some extra care is needed. Either you end also the last row with `\\` or define the environment as

```
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1]
  {\tabular{rC}}
  {\endtabular}
```

Of course here the argument is thrown away, but I'm confident you have other things to do with it. `;-)`.

Now

```
\begin{MyTabular}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{MyTabular}
```

will work.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Should `collcell` handle this without the need to use `\endtabular`? Not it is any more work to use `\endtabular`, just will probably forget next time I have this problem...

Comment: @PeterGrill At least it should be documented, but probably Martin didn't think of this.

Comment: @PeterGrill The need to use the `\endenvname` form is quite common in all environment collecting macros, AMS alignments and tabuarx for example have this (documented) feature.